# Charging my device from power bank with two-way USB-C cable?

Tags: usb, charging

So I have `Nexus 6p` with USB-C port and a `Xiaomi Pro 10000` power bank.

Charging my device with bundled `USB A -> microUSB -> USB-C Cable` works. But when I connect them with my `two-way USB-C cable` that was bundled with my phone **my phone is charging the power bank**. Is it possible to charge my phone instead?

Comment: It certainly is unusual- can you charge the power bank fully first and then see if the behaviour persists

Comment: I actually already got my answer from reddit. I guess I'll post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xiaomi Mi Pro **does not support** discharge through the USB-C port. It's not possible. I've tried everything.

If any store promises this feature this might just be a translation error ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/4t8euj/mi_power_bank_pro_doesnt_do_cc_output/))

Quickcharge through the usb-c port on nexus 6p is not possible too.